# Como emular el boton "atras" en Android : ocultar teclado virtual

Tags: android, edittext, teclado

en mi aplicacion estoy usando edittext, el cual puedo ocultarlo mediante una propiedad pero el teclado virtual queda en la pantalla, pero puedo ocultarlo mediante:

```
mTextoEditor.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

pero luego cuando deseo nuevamente usar el edittext no logro mostrarlo, entonces se me ocurrió si era posible emular el botón "atrás" por código pero sin haber presionado el botón, si lograra emular la función de presionar el botón de "atra" podría ocultar el teclado y volver a lanzarlo cuando lo necesita, alguien sabe si es posible lo que estoy imaginando y de ser posible como hacer esto?

Comment: Fijate si te sirve este código: public static void hideKeyboardFrom(Context context, View view) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}, lo saqué de SO, está en inglés,  si te interesa pego el link

Comment: Excelente, funciona, ya puedo ocultar y mostrar el teclado, Gracias!